# FIND THE HIGHEST AND LOWEST SALARY

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How to find Employee Name under each Manager with the highest and lowest salary

My table

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB      MGR    HIREDATE    SAL     COMM    DEPTNO.
7369    SMITH   CLERK     7902  17/12/1980  1250             20
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN  7902  20/02/1981  1600     300     30
7521    WARD    SALESMAN  7839  22/02/1981  1250     500     30
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN  7566  28/09/1981  1250    1400     30
7782    CLARK   MANAGER   7839  09/06/1981  2450             10
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST   7566  19/04/1987  3000             20
7839    KING    PRESIDENT 7566  17/11/1981  5000             10
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN  7788  08/09/1981  1500       0     30
7876    ADAMS   CLERK     7788  23/05/1987  1100             20
7900    JAMES   CLERK           03/12/1981   950             30
7902    FORD    ANALYST   7566  03/12/1981  3000             20
7934    MILLER  CLERK     7782  23/01/1982  1300             10
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mcve]. And lastly, don't SHOUT! (Or fix your broken keyboard.)

Comment: How do you want the output displayed? Suppose there's more than one employee for a manager with the highest or lowest salary: how do you want to handle that? Also, have you looked at any of the dozens of previous questions on ranking employees by salary? [Check out this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+top-n+salary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace T by your table name.

```
SELECT Mgr, EmpNo, EName, Sal
FROM (
    SELECT Mgr, EmpNo, EName, Sal,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Mgr ORDER BY Sal ASC ) AS RankAsc,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Mgr ORDER BY Sal DESC) AS RankDesc
    FROM T
) RankedSalaries
WHERE RankAsc = 1 OR RankDesc = 1
```

You can join `RankedSalaries` back to you table `ON Mgr = EmpNo` if you want the **name** of the manager.

Comment: highest and lowest salaries should be in different columns